# Script to compare to excel files and print differences

Tags: shell-script, shell, diff, excel

Is there any script handy to compare 2 excel sheets and print only their differences?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv) to export the sheets from an Excel file as CSV files, and then simply `diff` them.

Answer (score 1):

Convert XLS into csv files with comma delimiters
then sort the csv files and then do gvim -d csv1 csv2

this will simply print the differences in the XLS files